# how recursion works with inner methods?

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm trying to understand below code.

```
object ImplicitDemo {

  def calculate(f: => Int) = f * 37

  implicit class IntWithTimes(x: Int) {
        def times[A](f: => A) : Unit = {
          def loop(current: Int): Unit =
            if(current > 0) {
              f
              loop(current - 1)
            }
          f
          loop(x)
        }
  }
  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit ={

    (-5).times(println("abc"))

  }
}
```

`IntWithTimes` is a implicit class for `Int`, that mean it has everything which `Int` has plus `times` function.

when I call `(-5).times(println("abc"))`, `println("abc")` gets assigned to `f` in this part `f: => A` and `times` function has its own body too.

so when `times` body gets called, inner function `loop` gets called. How come `current` value is equivalent to `x` ? that's my first doubt..struggling to understand this.

second doubt is, how come its coming out from `loop` function body ? until `x > 0` it will be keep going in `if` condition and keep calling nested `loop` and once out (`x or current < 0`), it goes to `loop(x)` ..here it seems to be stuck in loop ..how come its coming out from `loop's` body ?

please help me to clear this doubts.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if expected or not but in your example `println` will be executed only once. You want a function parameter instead of pass-by-name if you want to re-execute `f` each time.

Comment: Also I recommend you learn how to use a debugger to step through code.

Answer (score 2):

> How come current value is equivalent to x ?

Because `loop` method is called with `x` first: `loop(x)`.

`current` is a parameter of the `loop` method, it does not exist anywhere else.

> how come its coming out from loop function body ? until x > 0 it will be keep going in if condition and keep calling nested loop

Because each time, `loop` is called with `current-1` (not with `x`), thus `current` at some point will equals 0 and the `if` part won't be called.

> and once out (x or current < 0), it goes to loop(x)

No. `loop(x)` is the 1st and only call from `times` to method `loop`. `def loop` does not call `loop`, it's a declaration of a method.

---

Note that there's nothing related to the pass-by-name parameter `f` in all the behaviours explained above.

---

EDIT: starting with `-5` will actually not even enter the recursion as you might have noticed.

Comment: why declaring loop and calling loop(x) both are required in  times function ? only declaring loop will not work ? Its quite confusing..dont you think so ?

Comment: Well, an initial value for the first call needs to be specified. Besides, declaring a function and calling it are normally separate things, in all programming languages. Finally, although this particular example happens to follow a pattern that would work with your proposed change to the language, lots of other examples wouldn't.

Comment: You can declare `loop` outside of `times` if this makes things clearer for you. But a method declaration does nothing by itself, you always have to call it at some point.

Comment: 1st part is loop is declared inside times and second is I'm calling it from main method,  upto here makes sense, then why its required loop(x) inside times ? This part looks strange to me... :(

Comment: You're not calling `loop` from your main method.

Comment: But am calling times where loop is defined, so isn't a same thing ? Because to reach loop, it has to go through from times..nope ?